# [0x End Point API https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?

Tags: bsc, 0x

where find the list of token available on API EndPoint https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?

When i'm trying to quote with https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote? all is ok for pair 'BUSD-WBNB', 'BUSD-WBNB' but ko with others, BUSD-CAKE 'USDT-HNT'... I think this pairs are not available on https://bsc.api.0x.org/ maybe i'm wrong ?

Best Regard

Answer (score 0):

0x API supports all tokens that are ERC20 compliant, but you need to pass the token address instead of symbols.

Check here the docs: https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote to know which variables to use and where.

Comment: Thank you Joao, it's ok when i get the token address all work fine !